# Changes gone after doing git rebase

Tags: git

I had made three commits  in git. Like this.

```
asaurab-3.desktop% git lg
* 931b405 - (HEAD -> saurabh, origin/saurabh) minor fixes (6 minutes ago) <Saurabh Kumar Agarwal>
* 838d366 - adding upload and download functionality (15 minutes ago) <Saurabh Kumar Agarwal>
* 0d62348 - first commit (7 days ago) <Saurabh Kumar Agarwal>
* 4797854 - (origin/mainline, origin/HEAD, mainline) commit  (2 weeks ago) <Perforce Administrator>
```

I wanted to squash these three commits
so i did

```
git rebase -i HEAD~3
```

It opened a window, with three commits. I replaces all three `pick` to `squash` and exist from editor using `:wq! .`

I got the error message

```
Cannot 'squash' without a previous commit
```

Now my `git lg` shows

```
* 4797854 - (HEAD, origin/mainline, origin/HEAD, mainline) commit (2 weeks ago) <Perforce Administrator>
```

All my changes are gone. How Can I get them back?

This is the output of `git status`

```
 git status
interactive rebase in progress; onto 4797854
No commands done.
Next commands to do (3 remaining commands):
   squash 0d62348 first commit
   squash 838d366 adding upload and download functionality
  (use "git rebase --edit-todo" to view and edit)
You are currently editing a commit while rebasing branch 'saurabh' on '4797854'.
  (use "git commit --amend" to amend the current commit)
  (use "git rebase --continue" once you are satisfied with your changes)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to the question is in git status only.

I did

```
git rebase --edit-todo
```

Then Earlier, I did squash in all three so this error was coming. I did pick for first commit and then squash for other two commit. then I saved my changes.

Then I did

```
git rebase --continue
```

It solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Your rebase has not completed yet. It's not an error, just a regular info while squashing. Run `rebase --continue` to finish the rebase.

```
$ git rebase --continue     # repeat the command until rebase complete
```

---

> All my changes are gone. How Can I get them back?

*OR*, you can abort the rebase and checkout to your desired commit. You can choose from `git reflog` output.

```
$ git rebase --abort       # abort/stop the rebase

$ git reflog               # copy your desired commit hash
$ git checkout <commit>    # I guess here, desired commit = 931b405
```

Now create a new branch

```
$ git checkout -b new-branch
```

You can squash last 3 commits by `soft reset` also.

```
$ git reset --soft HEAD~3
$ git add .
$ git commit -m 'Squash last three commits'

$ git push origin HEAD     # push to remote
```

Comment: Probably `git rebase --abort` makes more sense.  If rebase is erroring because the interactive script is broken, a `--continue` is unlikely to make much difference.

Comment: Yes, obviously `git rebase --abort` would stop the rebasing and back to the previous working tree. But I think here it's not an error (just regular info while rebasing)!

Comment: Yes @sajibkhan, It's not an error. It's regular info while rebasing. I just freaked out looking at git log.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying @sajibkhan - I misunderstood that.